# Restoring 40 GB Oracle backup to get db objects into Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, restore, oracle-xe

I have backup of oracle database size is almost 40 GB.This 40GB database backup contains lots of data that I don't care about. I just wanted to restore DB objects like tables structure, procedures, functions, triggers etc.
limitation: I have only Oracle 11G Express Edition(Free) which has limitation of only 10 GB.

is there any way to restore db objects from database backups?

Comment: So you would like to have the **DB structure**, but **no data**, right?

Answer (score 2):

## In case of `expdp/impdp` backup

```
impdp ... CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY
```

This will import only the DB objects, but no data. Should you require some data, you can get them for example on table, tablespace, or schema level:

```
impdp ... CONTENT=DATA_ONLY TABLES=my_table,my_table_2...
impdp ... CONTENT=DATA_ONLY TABLESPACES=tablespace_1,tablespace_2...
impdp ... CONTENT=DATA_ONLY SCHEMAS=schema_1,schema_2
```

## In case of `exp/imp` backup

You can try partially importing the tables or tablespaces (syntax same as with impdp):

```
imp ... TABLES=(jones.accts, scott.emp, scott.dept)
imp ... TABLESPACES=tablespace_1,tablespace_2...
```

## In case of `rman` backup

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719331/1667004) on partial restore from RMAN backup:

> RMAN is a physical backup - it copies files - and not surprisingly is restricted to physical restoration. As a consequence, its supported granularities are: block, file, **tablespace** and database.

So if you are lucky, and can get by with restoring a tablespace, it might work if there are different tablespaces in the backup and the one you need fits into the 10GB limit.

## Using Oracle 11g EE

If you have access to a full Oracle 11g (**beware**, the development license **prohibits** using it for internal data processing), just import the full DB, and do a selective export if none of the above is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing only structure with `metadata_only`

```
impdp scott/tiger DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY
```